# Unable to upload document to begin translations

Tags: google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

Have to get some localization done and hoping to use Google's translate toolkit to make .po files.

Despite setup billing, translate api, tried different browsers, accounts, new account... any time I click the upload button, I'm redirected (new tab) to the following url which reports a 404:
http://translate.google.com/toolkit/docupload?hl=en

I don't mind setting up by hand if upload doesn't work, but seems first step is upload.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same for me with hl=fr.

The issue is also on the google forum 
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/translator-toolkit-api/404/translator-toolkit-api/pB-EJM1EUAo/4BQIdkrsmPMJ

with no answer !

Strange to get 404 error from Google !

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to configure translate API, I'm now able to upload.